# Google maps iOS SDK breaks when a certain library is linked into the application

Tags: static-linking, google-maps-sdk-ios

**Background**

I am exploring using the Google Maps iOS SDK in an application that will also tightly depend on another statically linked C++ library. I have accomplished Google's prescribed Hello World program successfully with one caveat: using the `-ObjC` linker flag causes linker errors with my other library. To remedy this, I've been using the `-force_load /path/to/GoogleMaps` instead in order to only target the GoogleMaps framework, which seems to work well.

**The Problem**

When I reference certain (not all) classes inside the static library in custom C++ classes in my app (even if I don't instantiate those classes in the app itself) I repeatably see this strange runtime error:

```
ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). (null)
ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). (null)
ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). (null)
ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). (null)
```

The result in the app is that the pin and default off-white google background appear, but no maps are downloaded.

If I delete the app from the simulator or device and comment out the static library code and run the app, the maps load and everything works fine. Then, if I add those lines back in and run the app, I don't see these errors and the maps still load fine.

If I delete the app and leave those lines in for the firstrun of the app, I get these errors, but if I then comment out the library code and re-run it, the maps begin to load and all is well. Adding back in the library code does not cause the error messages/runtime issue to come back.

This leads me to believe that the error is occurring in some sort of initialization routine that is never subsequently called. I checked the files in the app sandbox and some are missing  until the maps load properly, which makes me think this is correct.

I have access to the source for the static library but obviously don't have access to the GoogleMaps SDK. There does not appear to be any clear documentation about what this error means, especially in my case where `(null)` is the final piece.

A few final notes that may or may not be relevant:

1. C++ Language Dialect: C++11 [-std=c++11]
2. C++ Standard Library: libc++

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is possibly the issue of duplicate global variables.
If you have saved your map key in some global variable then this is possible that your other c++ API is also using same variable for handling its own values. Try after changing the variable name in which your map key is saved.

This issue can be same for the functions as well but i think its least probable.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue. I have the same problem and so far I didn't find any solution.

Comment: @pawelini1 No, I was never able to resolve this. We ended up going with the google maps js framework. Sorry I could not be of help! If you do resolve it though, please post an answer here.